# DISM Error 2 with custom Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dism, imagex

I am trying to add storage drivers to a company customized version of Windows 7. I am able to mount this image using imagex, but when I try to put the drivers in using DISM, i get the following error:

> Error: 2
>   Unable to access the image.
>   Make sure that the image path and the Windows directory for the image exist and you have Read permissions on the folder.

I am able to confirm the path (H:\wim) and the permissions (local Admin on the machine, full control on the folder) so I am unsure what to do. Ive been banging my head against this for a week, so any help would be appreciated.

I am attempting this process from a VM without any antivirus software on it, and it is not connected to the internet.